# How to use Task in WebSocket class which do work inside infinite loop and reschedule Task work when websocket get new message

Tags: c#, websocket

I have WebSocket class where I want to do some infinite work using Tasks, when I receive onMessage event.

```
private void websocket_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message received: " + e.Message);
    // run or reshedule Tasks here
    if (e.Message == "Task1")
        task1.start();


}
```

Comment: MessageReceived is an event an you do not want to start a task inside an event.  I would send a message using InVoke to application layer and let application layer start the task.

Comment: Tasks are not threads. You don't "schedule" them. They represent an abstraction of *work to be done* rather than focussing on a *mechanism* for doing work (threads). When you have new work to be done, you create a new Task.